How to use aggregate function in oracle query
I am trying to use group by clause in below oracle query. I am not sure how i can use the aggregate function for query as fields are not numeric data. trying in oracle sql developer.
I have to group by usrnam field. I mentioned expected output below. could anyone help me for same? Thanks.
Select userroles.usrnam,userroles.treeauth,roles.role
from ROLES,USERROLES
WHERE ROLES.TREEAUTH = USERROLES.TREEAUTH AND USRNAM in ('XXXX','YYYY') group by userroles.treeauth,roles.role;

Table details:
table details



USRNAM
TREEAUTH
ROLE




YYYY
ML
Lab Manager


YYYY
TC
Lab-COA


YYYY
BB
B&S-Batch


YYYY
OR
Oper-Data-DCU


YYYY
L
IT - LIMS


YYYY
AD
Lab Admin


YYYY
DT
Data Users-Tags


YYYY
SP
Lab Special


XXXX
HD
Help Desk


YYYY
BS
B&S


YYYY
DC
Data Users


YYYY
TN
Lab


YYYY
BP
Planning-Batch


XXXX
L
IT - LIMS


YYYY
DB
B&S-Batch-Data


YYYY
DU
Data Users-COA



Expected output:
Expected_output



USRNAM
TREEAUTH
ROLE




YYYY
ML
Lab Manager



TC
Lab-COA



BB
B&S-Batch



OR
Oper-Data-DCU



L
IT - LIMS



AD
Lab Admin



DT
Data Users-Tags



SP
Lab Special



BS
B&S



DC
Data Users



TN
Lab



BP
Planning-Batch



DB
B&S-Batch-Data



DU
Data Users-COA


XXXX
HD
Help Desk



L
IT - LIMS



I tried aggregate function for usrnam but it didnt work as it is not numeric.

Maybe I didn't understand your question but it seems you're just ordering by username and not grouping anything

yes, this seems to be not about grouping or aggregating, but not displaying repeating results.

Use the SQL*Plus command BREAK:
BREAK ON usernam
SELECT u.usrnam,
       u.treeauth,
       r.role
FROM   roles r
       INNER JOIN userroles u
       ON r.treeauth = u.treeauth
WHERE  u.usernam IN ('XXXX','YYYY')
ORDER BY
       u.usernam DESC;


You can use the row_number() function
  SELECT CASE WHEN row_number() over (partition by userroles.usrnam order by roles.role) = 1
              THEN userroles.usrnam
              ELSE NULL
              END userroles.usrnam
       , userroles.treeauth
       , roles.role
    FROM roles,userroles
   WHERE roles.treeauth = userroles.treeauth 
     AND userroles.usrnam IN ('XXXX','YYYY')
ORDER BY userroles.usrnam, roles.role;

